What did the wear "абажур" look like?
Please note, I am asking about part of wear, not about accessory for a lamp.
Initially I thought it is something similar to visor cap, so it would be placed on forehead. But I read such passage in "Война и мир" -- "с абажуром на глазах". This would indicate it is more kind of glasses (see for example: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8#%D0%98%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2). Or somewhat similar to today sleep mask (only with the slots for some light to pass by).
So, how did it look like?

It did look like a visor cap, or a baseball cap without the crown.
From Wiktionary:

устар. козырёк, надеваемый на лоб для защиты глаз от света ◆ Князь в очках, с абажуром на глазах… сидел у открытого бюро. Л. Н. Толстой, «Война и мир»

